# How to join a subquery from two distinct select statements in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to add a select statement as a subquery into an existing statement and Im struggling as to where I would insert it at.  Currently I have two select statements and I'm trying to add the bottom one as a subquery into the top one, rather than creating two separate tables and joining them.

I would think that I should be adding the bottom statement right after the top select statement in parenthesis, before the "from" portion of code.  IS it possible to create a table that lists ID, name, 2021 sales, 2022 sales as four columns in one table?  Any help is appreciated.  I do have an invoicedate column which I am pulling from that is not included because I dont want it in my end result.

```
select customer.customerid, 
    CONCAT(customer.firstname, ' ', customer.lastname) AS full_name, invoice.total AS "2021 Sales"
    from customer
    inner join invoice
    on customer.customerid = invoice.customerid
    where invoicedate like '%2021%';


select customer.customerid, total AS "2022 Sales"
from customer
inner join invoice
on customer.customerid = invoice.customerid
where invoicedate like '%2022%'
```

Comment: What is data type for `invoicedate`? **ADD information to question**.

Comment: Presumably a customer can have many invoices so presumably first you need to be aggregating?

Comment: data type for invoicedate is text

Comment: so something like adding a distinct you mean to the customer id? or perhaps to the total

Answer (score 0):

You could use one query with two joins

```
select 
    customer.customerid, 
    CONCAT(customer.firstname, ' ', customer.lastname) AS full_name, 
    invoice_2021.total AS "2021 Sales",
    invoice_2022.total AS "2022 Sales"
from 
  customer
    inner join invoice invoice_2021 on 
        customer.customerid = invoice_2021.customerid and
        invoice_2021.invoicedate like '%2021%'
    inner join invoice invoice_2022 on 
        customer.customerid = invoice_2022.customerid and
        invoice_2022.invoicedate like '%2022%';
```

Comment: I only have one column for invoice.total, so im not sure how i could reference the one column as two names (invoice_2021.total and invoice_2022.total)

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer. I forgot I was joining to the same table in both joins, so I needed to give them aliases. I have corrected my answer.